# Extending one key on a Yup schema

Tags: validation, yup

I'm creating some Yup schemas, for example:

```js
    let validationSchema = yup.object({
      length: yup.number().min(1)
    });
```

Is there a way to extend this after it has been declared so it's like I set the schema like this?

```js
    let validationSchema = yup.object({
      length: yup.number().min(1).required(true)
    });
```

Answer (score 19):

The closest thing to schema extension/inheritance in Yup is to use
`object.shape` to create a new schema based on existing schema:
[Yup documentation](https://github.com/jquense/yup#objectshapefields-object-nosortedges-arraystring-string-schema)

`object.shape(fields: object, noSortEdges?: Array<[string, string]>): Schema`

> Define the keys of the object and the schemas for said keys.
> Note that you can chain shape method, which acts like object extends

```js
const baseSchema = Yup.object().shape({
   id: string().isRequired(),  
  name: string().isRequired()
})

const someSchema = baseSchema.shape({
   id: number().isRequired(),
   age: number().isRequired()
})
```

which is equivalent to:

```js
const someSchema = Yup.object().shape({
   id: number().isRequired(), // notice how 'id' is overridden by child schema
   name: string().isRequired(),
   age: number().isRequired()
})
```

Another way is to use `concat(schema)` to create a new schema instance by combing two schemas:  [Yup documentation](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedconcatschema-schema-schema)

> `mixed.concat(schema: Schema): Schema`
> Creates a new instance of the schema by combining two schemas. Only schemas of the same type can be concatenated.

```js
const baseSchema = Yup.object().shape({
   name: string().isRequired()
})

const someSchema = baseSchema.concat(
   Yup.object().shape({
    age: number().isRequired()
}))

// someSchema will be equipped with both `name` and `age` attributes
```

Please note that `concat` only works when two schema objects have different properties or same properties with exact same type.

Comment: If you are using React and you are having the ESLint error [Prop type "object" is forbidden](https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/forbid-prop-types.md) when using `shape`, I found that the `concat` method does not produce such error. Although, I have not dug deep as to why.